# Matlab: delete duplicate consecutive values in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, duplicates

I have this array

```
Y=[618 1 631 618 631 618 631 631 631 618 631 627 631 631]
```

and I want to trasform it in:

```
[618 1 631 618 631 618 631 618 631 627 631]
```

I have used this code

```
[~,index] = unique(Y,'first');       
Y(sort(index))
```

but the answer is this, that it's different from the result that I want.
ans =
   618     1   631   627

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain what language this is ?

Comment: Sorry, it's matlab: I have add the tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this? (I really thought this was a duplicate, but I did not find one that had similar title - I'm sure the content came up somewhere)

```
NewY = Y([1,diff(Y)]~=0)

NewY =  
618 1 631 618 631 618 631 618 631 627 631
```

You can also save a byte in the notation by doing:

```
NewY = Y(~~[1,diff(Y)])
```

As suggested by @AndrasDeak :D